# Синтаксис javascript - аналог jquery синтаксису

Tags: javascript, jquery

В jQuery есть синтаксис

```js
$("#idelem")
$(".classelem")
$(tag)
```

Какой синтаксис в javascript (как обратится к элементу DOM)?

Comment: Никакого, потому что `method` в вашем примере это метод jQuery.

Comment: $() это функция javascript

Comment: Вернее покажите лучше какую задачу вы хотите решить. Ну или посмотрите тут http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: долго рассказывать, почитайте https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference

Comment: ну если хотите что-то с элементами поделать, почитайте про `querySelector` и `querySelectorall`, но все равно как в jQuery не всегда получится

Comment: `document.getElementById()` - как первое, прокатит
`document.getElementsByClassName()` - а это должно помочь для второго случая